# Merging two functions and executing in sequence

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm having a few problems with this, so I'll try to keep it simple. What's happening in the first script is a new Google doc file gets made from a copy of a "master" doc I've defined, which gets its data populated from Form submissions, and that new copy is ultimately moved to a Folder on my Drive. The second script is supposed to send that copied file to the Google Cloud Print. The first script works perfect; I have it triggered on a form submit. The second script works by itself, but only when I explicitly define the master doc ID in the "content" section. Because with each Form submission a new doc gets made, I was having trouble integrating the new doc's ID with the second script. Right now, I tried pulling from the ***var file***, but that's not working. I might have a syntax issue.

My other problem is I need to merge my second script with the first, in a way that gets triggered on the same Form Submit and probably execute after the PDF creation and Email send, but before it gets moved to the folder.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

And I've removed some of my IDs and sensitive information where you only see double quotes.

```js
// Work Order


// Get template from Google Docs and name it
var docTemplate = ""; // *** replace with your template ID ***
var docName = "Work Order";

function addDates() {
  var date = new Date(); // your form date
  var holiday = ["09/04/2017", "10/09/2017", "11/23/2017", "12/24/2017", "12/25/2017", "01/01/2018"]; //Define holiday dates in MM/dd/yyyy
  var days = 5; //No of days you want to add
  date.setDate(date.getDate());
  var counter = 0;
  if (days > 0) {
    while (counter < days) {
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
      var check = date.getDay();
      var holidayCheck = holiday.indexOf(Utilities.formatDate(date, "EDT", "MM/dd/yyyy"));
      if (check != 0 && check != 6 && holidayCheck == -1) {
        counter++;
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log(date) //for this example will give 08/16/2017
  return date;
}

// When Form Gets submitted
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  //Get information from form and set as variables
  var email_address = "";
  var job_name = e.values[1];
  var ship_to = e.values[11];
  var address = e.values[12];
  var order_count = e.values[7];
  var program = e.values[2];
  var workspace = e.values[3];
  var offer = e.values[4];
  var sort_1 = e.values[5];
  var sort_2 = e.values[6];
  var image_services = e.values[9];
  var print_services = e.values[10];
  var priority = e.values[13];
  var notes = e.values[14];
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EDT", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  var expirationDate = Utilities.formatDate(addDates(), "EDT", "MM/dd/yyyy");

  // Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc's id
  var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
    .makeCopy(docName + ' for ' + job_name)
    .getId();
  // Open the temporary document
  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
  // Get the document's body section
  var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

  // Replace place holder keys,in our google doc template  
  copyBody.replaceText('keyJobName', job_name);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyShipTo', ship_to);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyAddress', address);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyOrderCount', order_count);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyProgram', program);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyWorkspace', workspace);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyOffer', offer);
  copyBody.replaceText('keySort1', sort_1);
  copyBody.replaceText('keySort2', sort_2);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyImageServices', image_services);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyPrintServices', print_services);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyPriority', priority);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyNotes', notes);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyDate', formattedDate);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyDue', expirationDate);

  // Save and close the temporary document
  copyDoc.saveAndClose();

  // Convert temporary document to PDF by using the getAs blob conversion
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

  // Attach PDF and send the email
  var subject = "New Job Submission";
  var body = "Here is the work order for " + job_name + "";
  MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {
    htmlBody: body,
    attachments: pdf
  });

  // Move file to folder
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId);
  DriveApp.getFolderById("").addFile(file);
  file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
}
```

```js
function printGoogleDocument(file, docName) {
  // For notes on ticket options see https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/cdd?hl=en
  var ticket = {
    version: "1.0",
    print: {
      color: {
        type: "STANDARD_COLOR"
      },
      duplex: {
        type: "NO_DUPLEX"
      },
    }
  };

  var payload = {
    "printerid": "",
    "content": file,
    "title": docName,
    "contentType": "google.kix", // allows you to print google docs
    "ticket": JSON.stringify(ticket),
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit', {
    method: "POST",
    payload: payload,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + GoogleCloudPrint.getCloudPrintService().getAccessToken()
    },
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  });

  // If successful, should show a job here: https://www.google.com/cloudprint/#jobs

  response = JSON.parse(response);
  if (response.success) {
    Logger.log("%s", response.message);
  } else {
    Logger.log("Error Code: %s %s", response.errorCode, response.message);
  }
  return response;
}
```

**

### Update 8/14 with Sandy Good's suggestion:

**
I've attempted to do what you suggested, but now it's not creating the doc or sending to the cloud print. Any thoughts?

```js
// Work Order


// Get template from Google Docs and name it
var docTemplate = ""; // *** replace with your template ID ***
var docName = "Work Order";

function addDates() {
  var date = new Date(); // your form date
  var holiday = ["09/04/2017", "10/09/2017", "11/23/2017", "12/24/2017", "12/25/2017", "01/01/2018"]; //Define holiday dates in MM/dd/yyyy
  var days = 5; //No of days you want to add
  date.setDate(date.getDate());
  var counter = 0;
  if (days > 0) {
    while (counter < days) {
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
      var check = date.getDay();
      var holidayCheck = holiday.indexOf(Utilities.formatDate(date, "EDT", "MM/dd/yyyy"));
      if (check != 0 && check != 6 && holidayCheck == -1) {
        counter++;
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log(date) //for this example will give 08/16/2017
  return date;
}

function createNewDoc(values) {
  var email_address = "";
  var job_name = e.values[1];
  var ship_to = e.values[11];
  var address = e.values[12];
  var order_count = e.values[7];
  var program = e.values[2];
  var workspace = e.values[3];
  var offer = e.values[4];
  var sort_1 = e.values[5];
  var sort_2 = e.values[6];
  var image_services = e.values[9];
  var print_services = e.values[10];
  var priority = e.values[13];
  var notes = e.values[14];
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EDT", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  var expirationDate = Utilities.formatDate(addDates(), "EDT", "MM/dd/yyyy");

  // Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc's id
  var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
    .makeCopy(docName + ' for ' + job_name)
    .getId();
  // Open the temporary document
  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
  // Get the document's body section
  var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

  // Replace place holder keys,in our google doc template  
  copyBody.replaceText('keyJobName', job_name);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyShipTo', ship_to);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyAddress', address);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyOrderCount', order_count);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyProgram', program);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyWorkspace', workspace);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyOffer', offer);
  copyBody.replaceText('keySort1', sort_1);
  copyBody.replaceText('keySort2', sort_2);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyImageServices', image_services);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyPrintServices', print_services);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyPriority', priority);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyNotes', notes);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyDate', formattedDate);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyDue', expirationDate);

  // Save and close the temporary document
  copyDoc.saveAndClose();

  // Convert temporary document to PDF by using the getAs blob conversion
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

  // Attach PDF and send the email
  var subject = "New Job Submission";
  var body = "Here is the work order for " + job_name + "";
  MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {
    htmlBody: body,
    attachments: pdf
  });

  // Move file to folder
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId);
  DriveApp.getFolderById("").addFile(file);
  file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
}

function printGoogleDocument(file, docName) {
  // For notes on ticket options see https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/cdd?hl=en
  var ticket = {
    version: "1.0",
    print: {
      color: {
        type: "STANDARD_COLOR"
      },
      duplex: {
        type: "NO_DUPLEX"
      },
    }
  };

  var payload = {
    "printerid": "",
    "content": file,
    "title": docName,
    "contentType": "google.kix", // allows you to print google docs
    "ticket": JSON.stringify(ticket),
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit', {
    method: "POST",
    payload: payload,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + GoogleCloudPrint.getCloudPrintService().getAccessToken()
    },
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  });

  // If successful, should show a job here: https://www.google.com/cloudprint/#jobs

  response = JSON.parse(response);
  if (response.success) {
    Logger.log("%s", response.message);
  } else {
    Logger.log("Error Code: %s %s", response.errorCode, response.message);
  }
  return response;
}

// When Form Gets submitted
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  //Get information from form and set as variables
  var values = e.values;
  createNewDoc(values);
  printGoogleDocument(file, docName);
}
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to move the code for `printGoogleDocument()` to `onFormSubmit(e)` if that is what you are thinking of doing.  In fact, I would create another separate function for creating the Doc, and move the code for creating the Doc to that function.  The first thing you should do is create a new variable named `values` and put all the values into it:  `var values = e.values;`  Except for that one line of code, I'd move all the code from `onFormSubmit(e)` to `createNewDoc(values)`;  Then call both `createNewDoc(values)` and `printGoogleDocument(file, docName)` from `onFormSubmit(e)`

Comment: @SandyGood Thanks. I've updated my original post to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: In your `createNewDoc` function, you have statements: `var job_name = e.values[1];`  You need to remove `e.`  That is because `values` is now `e`.  So, change to:  `var job_name = values[1];`

Comment: @SandyGood Perfect, that worked on creating the doc and moving to my drive folder. Last problem I have is sending to my Cloud Print. The function is executing properly on form submit, but it's not actually sending my file to the Cloud Print. Do you think it's because the last step in function createNewDoc(values) is file.getParents().next().removeFile(file)?

Meaning the file variable is getting removed, but the printGoogleDocument function is still trying to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have more questions in regards to this project, but I think this specific question has been answered, so here's the final code for future reference.

```js
// Work Order


// Get template from Google Docs and name it
var docTemplate = ""; // *** replace with your template ID ***
var docName = "Work Order";

function addDates() {
  var date = new Date(); // your form date
  var holiday = ["09/04/2017", "10/09/2017", "11/23/2017", "12/24/2017", "12/25/2017", "01/01/2018"]; //Define holiday dates in MM/dd/yyyy
  var days = 5; //No of days you want to add
  date.setDate(date.getDate());
  var counter = 0;
  if (days > 0) {
    while (counter < days) {
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
      var check = date.getDay();
      var holidayCheck = holiday.indexOf(Utilities.formatDate(date, "EDT", "MM/dd/yyyy"));
      if (check != 0 && check != 6 && holidayCheck == -1) {
        counter++;
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log(date) //for this example will give 08/16/2017
  return date;
}

function createNewDoc(values) {
//Get information from form and set as variables
  var email_address = "";
  var job_name = values[1];
  var ship_to = values[11];
  var address = values[12];
  var order_count = values[7];
  var program = values[2];
  var workspace = values[3];
  var offer = values[4];
  var sort_1 = values[5];
  var sort_2 = values[6];
  var image_services = values[9];
  var print_services = values[10];
  var priority = values[13];
  var notes = values[14];
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EDT", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  var expirationDate = Utilities.formatDate(addDates(), "EDT", "MM/dd/yyyy");

  // Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc's id
  var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
    .makeCopy(docName + ' for ' + job_name)
    .getId();
  // Open the temporary document
  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
  // Get the document's body section
  var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

  // Replace place holder keys,in our google doc template  
  copyBody.replaceText('keyJobName', job_name);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyShipTo', ship_to);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyAddress', address);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyOrderCount', order_count);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyProgram', program);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyWorkspace', workspace);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyOffer', offer);
  copyBody.replaceText('keySort1', sort_1);
  copyBody.replaceText('keySort2', sort_2);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyImageServices', image_services);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyPrintServices', print_services);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyPriority', priority);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyNotes', notes);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyDate', formattedDate);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyDue', expirationDate);

  // Save and close the temporary document
  copyDoc.saveAndClose();

  // Convert temporary document to PDF by using the getAs blob conversion
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

  // Attach PDF and send the email
  var subject = "New Job Submission";
  var body = "Here is the work order for " + job_name + "";
  MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {
    htmlBody: body,
    attachments: pdf
  });

  // Move file to folder
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId);
  DriveApp.getFolderById("").addFile(file);
  file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
}

function printGoogleDocument(file, docName) {
  // For notes on ticket options see https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/cdd?hl=en
  var ticket = {
    version: "1.0",
    print: {
      color: {
        type: "STANDARD_COLOR"
      },
      duplex: {
        type: "NO_DUPLEX"
      },
    }
  };

  var payload = {
    "printerid": "",
    "content": file,
    "title": docName,
    "contentType": "google.kix", // allows you to print google docs
    "ticket": JSON.stringify(ticket),
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit', {
    method: "POST",
    payload: payload,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + GoogleCloudPrint.getCloudPrintService().getAccessToken()
    },
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  });

  // If successful, should show a job here: https://www.google.com/cloudprint/#jobs

  response = JSON.parse(response);
  if (response.success) {
    Logger.log("%s", response.message);
  } else {
    Logger.log("Error Code: %s %s", response.errorCode, response.message);
  }
  return response;
}

// When Form Gets submitted
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var values = e.values;
  createNewDoc(values);
  printGoogleDocument(file, docName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is what you are after, but the easiest way to execute functions consecutively is to pass a callback function as an argument to your function.

Here's the list of simple functions assigned to variables.

```
var addFive = function(number, callback){

 number += 5;

  if (callback) {

    return callback(number);

  }

  return number;


}

var multiplyByFive = function(number, callback){

 number *= 5;

  if (callback) {

    return callback(number);

  }

  return number;


}

var subtractFive = function(number, callback){

number -= 5;

  if (callback) {

    return callback(number);
  }

  return number;

}
```

You can then just chain call them like this.

```
function test() {

  var result =  addFive(7, function(number) {

   return multiplyByFive(number, function(number){

     return subtractFive(number);

    });

  });

  Logger.log(result); //logs (7 + 5) * 5 - 5 = 55


}
```

Of course, if your functions only perform operations like creating files and don't return values, feel free to omit the 'return' statement.